# Помогите оптимизировать SQL-запрос для Wiki-движка

Tags: php, sql, sqlite3

Ради изучения PHP пишу блог по принципу Wiki-системы, где каждый анонимус мог бы писать статьи, и каждый любой другой анонимус мог бы вносить исправления. Полностью открытая система.

Имеется три таблички, blog_articles с мета-данными статей: красивый URI, разрешено ли комментировании статьи и т.п., text_articles с самим текстом статей и revision_articles со историей изменений: автор, дата, причина редактирования и т.п., отсюда уже ссылки на blog_articles и text_articles.

Составил следующий SQL-запрос, который пока что удовлетворяет нужды, но поскольку опыта у меня катастрофически мало, очень хочу, чтобы вы помогли мне оптимизировать этот SQL-запрос!

```
-- выбираем все статьи
SELECT * FROM blog_articles

-- берём первую ревизию
INNER JOIN revision_articles AS r_init ON (
  r_init.article_id = blog_articles.article_id AND r_init.id = (
      SELECT id FROM revision_articles WHERE article_id = blog_articles.article_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
  )
)

-- берём последнюю ревизию
INNER JOIN revision_articles AS r_last ON (
  r_last.article_id = blog_articles.article_id AND r_last.id = (
      SELECT id FROM revision_articles WHERE article_id = blog_articles.article_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
  )
)

-- достаём актуальный текст из последней ревизии
INNER JOIN text_articles ON text_articles.text_id = r_last.text_id

-- автор статьи тот, кто создал первую ревизию
LEFT JOIN user ON user.user_id = r_init.author_id

-- прочие мелочи
WHERE blog_articles.blog_id IN (3, 4) AND article_type = "article" AND is_published IS NULL
ORDER BY article_id DESC
LIMIT ' . (((int) $last - (int) $page) * 10) . ', 10
```

Структура таблиц выглядит следующим образом

```
CREATE TABLE 'blog_articles'
(
    'article_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    'article_object' TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE 'text_articles'
(
    'article_id' INTEGER,
    'text_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    'text' TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE 'revision_articles'
(
    'article_id' INTEGER,
    'id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    'date' DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    'text_id' INTEGER,
    'text_comment' NVARCHAR(255),
    'author_ip' NVARCHAR(45),
    'author_agent' NVARCHAR(255)
);
```

Одна запись в blog_articles ссылается на множественные записи в revision_articles, откуда достаются только первая и последняя, из text_articles достаётся последняя запись соответствующая последней ревизии.

Возможно ли сделать как-то лучше SQL-запрос? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Ещё хотелось бы прикрутить "автоподтверждение" к ревизиям. Сейчас любой анонимус может внести исправление, добавить ревизию и новый текст сразу отобразиться в статье. Защиты от вандализма никакой. Я планировал сделать так, чтобы доставался не "самый последний текст статьи", а "самый последний текст от автора", т.е. необходимо ещё сделать проверку по автору.

То есть, вы написали статью на сайт, в ревизии вы сохранились как author_id = NULL, анонимус. Затем кто-то привелигованный (автор статьи, админ и т.п.) прочитал вашу ревизию и сохранил её, в ревизии он сохранился как author_id = 1 и user.status = ADMIN, значит эту ревизию можно считать за последнюю актуальную, а значит её текст можно отобразить в статье.

Сейчас вложенный SELECT предполагает, что в таком случае будет необходимо лепить ещё один JOIN и там, для проверки авторов, и я бы так и сделал, но прежде хочу задать этот вопрос вам: если этот SQL-запрос возможно сделать как-то лучше, то помогите пожалуйста, и уже тогда, с новым улучшенным SQL-запросом буду думать над проверкой авторов и "автоподтверждением" ревизий.

Спасибо.

Comment: У вас база слишком правильно построена. Для оптимизации иногда приходится отклонятся от НФ. Я бы для начала автора сохранил бы не только в первой ревизии, но и в blog_articles. Не пришлось бы за первой версией лазить. И вопрос пагинации надо отдельно прорабатывать. limit хорош, когда offset не превышает дессятков записей, а если он будет расти больше, то будет провал производительности. И для оптимизации запросов ключевую роль имеют планы выполнения, без них ничего сделать нельзя. Может у вас где нибудь индекса нужного нет и система из за этого загибаться начнет (а вы их так же не указали)

Comment: Кстати, а зачем текст в отдельную таблицу вынесен ? У вас часты ситуации, когда у двух ревизий одинаковый текст ?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. На счёт автора вы правы, вы так же подсказали, что в blog_articles можно хранить текущий актуальный текст статьи, а не лазить за ним в text_articles. То есть, анонимусы вносят свои правки, вандалят как хотят, но текст вносится в blog_articles только по мановению руки админа/редактора/автора и т.д. Таким образом решается проблема с кучей JOIN'ов, а blog_articles выполняет роль "всегда актуального кэша" полного набора данных из всех таблиц. Просто супер!

Comment: И еще author_ip и author_agent в ревизии немного напрягает. Информация нужна по хорошему только админам и может модераторам. На протяжении сессии она у автора не меняется. Он может отредактировать сотни статей с одного ip/браузера.Может вынести ее. У вас же все равно какие нибудь "сессии" должны фиксироваться. Вот какой нибудь id сессии и положить

Comment: Текст хранится отдельно потому что "да" =), ревизия может иметь чисто технический характер, когда админ создаёт ревизию не чтобы править текст, а чтобы сказать системе "я её посмотрел, значит всё хорошо", а дублировать текст второй раз уже не нужно. По поводу offset/limit, по правде говоря впервые слышу, что пагинация таким образом может вызывать проблемы. Как же тогда делать? И да, ip/agent доступен не каждому, и сессии как таковых тоже нет, каждый анонимус пришёл, нагадил в базу и ушёл. Поэтому не вижу причин, чтобы отдельно для него хранить сессию и привязывать данные к ней. :)

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @Spoofing Тут где то с месяц назад пробегал вопрос по сильным тормозам системы ... Там какой то робот из интернета лез на последнюю страницу и offset был под 3000 так вот sql и приходилось перебирать 3000 записей пока дойдет до нужных. Пока сортировка по article_id может помнить страницу как последнюю отображенную id, и тогда where id<N, правда через страницу так не перескочишь и вообще куча сложностей